# Fixed-Point-Math - Is the conversion from float safe to always yield the same result?

Tags: android, c++, ios, floating-point, fixed-point

I'm using libfixmath for a simulation the needs to take place on two devices (iOS / Android) at the same time and be perfectly accurate.

The simulation needs to be fed with some initial float parameters. I'm wondering, if it's safe to use floats and then convert them into fix16_t in the way below (the function is from the library) or if I need to feed the simulation with fix16_t values already?

Hence, is it possible that two different devices calculate different results with the same input for the function below, because of floating point inaccuracy?

```
typedef int32_t fix16_t;
static const fix16_t fix16_one = 0x00010000; /*!< fix16_t value of 1 */

static inline fix16_t fix16_from_float(float a)
{
    float temp = a * fix16_one; 

    // rounding
    temp += (temp >= 0) ? 0.5f : -0.5f;
    return (fix16_t)temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that:

- both machines use IEEE-754 single precision floating point representation for `float`, and
- the value `a` is "reasonable"

the conversion should be portable, with the possible exception of the case where the absolute value of `a` is just slightly less than 0.5×2<sup>−16</sup>.

Multiplying a (binary) floating point number by a power of 2 (in this case 2<sup>16</sup>) is precise provided that it doesn't cause a floating point overflow (or underflow in the case of negative powers of 2). Every floating point implementation should handle that multiplication in precisely the same way.

The C++ standard requires conversion from floating point to integer types to truncate towards 0, so the rounding strategy is correct.

Adding 0.5 to `temp` will produce the correct result in almost all cases.

For intermediate values of `temp`, the result will be precise.

If `temp` is greater than 2<sup>23</sup>, the addition will have no effect, but there is no fraction to be rounded, so the end result will be predictable as long as there is no overflow when casting back to an integer.

If `temp` is less than 1.0, the sum will be imprecise, because the exponent will be increased. The addition should then *round* to produce the correct result. Here, the only case of interest is where the truncated sum might be either 0 or 1; if `temp` is not close to 0.5, the sum cannot be 1.0 and the truncated sum must be 0. If `temp` is at least 0.5, the sum must be at least 1.0, and the truncated sum must be 1.

But if `temp` is just slightly less than 0.5, rounding of the sum may be significant. In particular, if `temp` is precisely 0.5−2<sup>−25</sup>, there is an ambiguity. The result of the sum will be 1.0−2<sup>−25</sup>, but this value is not precisely representable as an IEEE-754 single-precision float. Moreover, the error term is precisely one-half of a ULP. So the result needs to be rounded, and that will obey the rounding mode of the implementation.

The default rounding mode for IEEE-754 is ["banker's rounding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), where rounding of a value of exactly one-half is towards whichever of the two possibilities has a 0 as its low-order bit. That will favour rounding 0.5−2<sup>−25</sup> + 0.5 to 1.0, which will produce the incorrect integer truncation 1. However, it is possible that a given implementation uses a different rounding mode, perhaps because it has been set using [`std::fesetround`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround).

All of the above applies equally to negative values.

Comment: Thanks for this really in-detail answer!